# 500 in POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am building edit post system using jquery  and ajax in laravel 5.2.
When i click on save changes button in my bootstrap modal, the following error is displayed:

> ```
> Error: POST http://localhost:8000/edit 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> send @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4
>
> ajax @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous function) @ myplace.js:24
>
> dispatch @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3
>
> r.handle @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3
> ```

**js code**:

```
$('#modal-save').on('click' , function() {

$.ajax({

    method : 'POST' ,
    url : url ,
    data: { body: $('#post-body').val(), postid: '' , _token: token }})

.done(function(msg) {

    console.log(msg['message']);

});});
```

included in my **view file**:

```
<script>
var token='{{ Session::token() }}';
var url='{{  route('edit') }}' ;
</script>
```

Comment: 500 is an internal Server error. Look in the Server logfiles and you should see what is happend

Comment: @Jens server log: [2016-06-20 16:17:07] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'url' not found' in E:\wamp\www\yash1\storage\framework\views\0ea06b81317c97d37b404ec2dd73a20f2f157c‌​ad.php:8

Answer (score 1):

First, as suggested, you have to check your log for a detailed cause. Futhermore, I suppose that you need to stringify your data:

```
$.ajax({

 method : 'POST' ,
 url : url ,
 data: JSON.stringify({ body: $('#post-body').val(), postid: '' , _token: token  })
}).done(function(msg) {

 console.log(msg['message']);

});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the url is correct? I suppose that you are trying to implement a CRUD with laravel. If I am right the edit url is: /nerds/{id}/edit with route name nerds.edit. Here some tips https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Comment: server log: [2016-06-20 16:17:07] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'url' not found' in E:\wamp\www\yash1\storage\framework\views\0ea06b81317c97d37b404ec2dd73a20f2f157cad.php:8